# PHP syntax error in UPDATE table statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error

I am trying to update a table named mineraltable (which has primary key named ItemID) with foreign keys values from a sourcelocationtable (LocationID), imagetable (ImageID), itemtypetable (ItemTypeID) and donatortable (DonatorID).

I want the user to be able to select location, image, itemtype and donator values from dropdown select boxes the value will be stored in a variable and then the mineraltable will be updated with the foreign key numbers of the value displayed in the dropdown select boxes.

The relationship of the latter 4 tables to the mineraltable is 1-Many therefore I can't use a junction table to hold the foreign keys they must go in the mineral table.

After trying to run the following sql code

```
UPDATE mineraltable SET LocationID='160',ItemTypeID='1',ImageID='6',    DonatorID='4' WHERE ItemID='372'
```

This is it converted to PHP formatting with my php variables substituted for numerical values.

```
$sql = "UPDATE mineraltable\n"
    . "SET LocationID=\'$LocationID\', ItemTypeID=\'$ItemTypeID\', ImageID=\'$ImageID\', DonatorID=\'$DonatorID\'\n"
    . "WHERE ItemID=\'ItemID\'"
```

I found that the sql code written into my local server xampp with numerical values runs successfully and updates the foreign key values in the mineraltable, but when  I run the php version of this code in my web browser I get the error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'166\', ItemTypeID=\'6\', ImageID=\'11\', DonatorID=\'4\' WHERE
>   ItemID=\'371\'' at line 2”

I have looked at the on StackOverFlow for another method of updating foreign keys I have found that you can temporarily remove the foreign key to execute code and then reapply the foreign key. But this was not recommended.

**I have gone through the code multiple times and cannot see any errors. Can someone please tell me as I am new to php coding where the syntax error is being caused? Any constructive answers much appreciated.**

I have followed the answer in [How to update foreign key value in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541446/how-to-update-foreign-key-value-in-mysql-database) to get the UPDATE statement code. But have also looked at 
[1]: [Syntax error in update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881573/syntax-error-in-update-statement) to troubleshoot the problem, but the example in the latter link was not similar to mine.

Here is the php code for the whole input form.

```
   $debugMode = true;

   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $dbname = 'rockandmineraldb';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo 'Connected successfully';


   $sql = 'SELECT LocationID,Site,Region,Country,Continent FROM sourcelocationtable';
   mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$SiteOptionData="";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $LocationID = $row['LocationID']; 
         $Site = $row['Site'];
         $Region = $row['Region'];
         $Country = $row['Country'];
         $Continent = $row['Continent'];

       $SiteOptionData .= "<option value-\"$LocationID\">$Site $Region $Country $Continent</option>";

}




   $sql = 'SELECT DonatorID,DonatorFN,DonatorLN FROM donatortable';
   mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$DonatorOptionData="";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $DonatorID = $row['DonatorID']; 
         $DonatorFN = $row['DonatorFN'];
         $DonatorLN = $row['DonatorLN'];


       $DonatorOptionData .= "<option value-\"$DonatorID\">$DonatorFN $DonatorLN</option>";

}


   $sql = 'SELECT ItemTypeID,ItemType FROM itemtypetable';
   mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$ItemTypeOptionData="";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $ItemTypeID = $row['ItemTypeID']; 
         $ItemType = $row['ItemType'];



       $ItemTypeOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemTypeID\">$ItemType</option>";

}

   $sql = 'SELECT ImageID,Image FROM imagetable';
   mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$ImageOptionData="";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $ImageID = $row['ImageID']; 
         $Image = $row['Image'];

       $ImageOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ImageID\">$Image</option>";

}

 $sql = 'SELECT ItemID,TrayBoxNo,ItemInBox,Name FROM mineraltable';
   mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$ItemOptionData="";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $ItemID = $row['ItemID']; 
         $TrayBoxNo = $row['TrayBoxNo'];
         $ItemInBox = $row['ItemInBox'];
         $Name = $row['Name'];



       $ItemOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemID\">$TrayBoxNo,$ItemInBox,$Name</option>";

}
   mysql_free_result($retval);
   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

if(isset($_POST['Item'])){ $ItemID== $_POST['Item']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Location'])){ $LocationID = $_POST['Location']; } 
if(isset($_POST['ItemType'])){ $ItemTypeID = $_POST['ItemType']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Image'])){ $ImageID = $_POST['Image']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Donator'])){ $DonatorID = $_POST['Donator']; } 


if(isset)

$sql = "UPDATE mineraltable\n"
    . "SET LocationID=\'$LocationID\', ItemTypeID=\'$ItemTypeID\', ImageID=\'$ImageID\', DonatorID=\'$DonatorID\'\n"
    . "WHERE ItemID=\'$ItemID\'";


            mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);


?>



  <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table>
 <tr>
                    <td>Select Site</td>
                    <td>
                        <select size="10" name="Location" multiple="multiple" id="Location">


                            <?php echo $SiteOptionData; ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

    <br>


                <tr>
    <td>Select Donator</td>
                    <td>
                        <select size="10" name="Donator" multiple="multiple" id="Donator">


                            <?php echo $DonatorOptionData; ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

<br>

                <tr>
    <td>Select ItemType</td>
                    <td>
                        <select size="10" name="ItemType" multiple="multiple" id="ItemType">


                            <?php echo $ItemTypeOptionData; ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

<br>

                <tr>
    <td>Select Image</td>
                    <td>


                        <select size="10" name="Image" multiple="multiple" id="Image">


                        <?php echo $ImageOptionData; ?> 

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

    <td>Select Item</td>
                    <td>
                        <select size="10" name="Item" multiple="multiple" id="Item">


                            <?php echo $ItemOptionData; ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>


</table>

  <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="update">

</form>
```

Comment: Try and remove the line break \n from the query you put into $sql.

Comment: You don't have to escape `'` inside `"` or `"` inside `'`.

Comment: DO you know what for do you use `\'`?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone I have removed the \n and the backslashes and got the code working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql = "UPDATE mineraltable
        SET LocationID='$LocationID', ItemTypeID='$ItemTypeID', ImageID='$ImageID', 
     DonatorID='$DonatorID' WHERE ItemID='ItemID' ";
```

Please remove `\n` and `backslash` from query. it is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the help I have removed the \n and the backslashes and got the code working

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$sql = "UPDATE mineraltable"
. " SET LocationID='$LocationID', ItemTypeID='$ItemTypeID', ImageID='$ImageID', DonatorID='$DonatorID'"
. " WHERE ItemID='$ItemID'"
```

You used double-quote so you shouldn't escape single-quote.

Answer (score 0):

in your query instead of

```
"UPDATE mineraltable\n"
    . "SET LocationID=\'$LocationID\', ItemTypeID=\'$ItemTypeID\', ImageID=\'$ImageID\', DonatorID=\'$DonatorID\'\n"
    . "WHERE ItemID=\'$ItemID\'"
```

use

```
"UPDATE mineraltable "
    . "SET LocationID='$LocationID', ItemTypeID='$ItemTypeID', ImageID='$ImageID', DonatorID='$DonatorID' "
    . "WHERE ItemID='$ItemID'"
```